# guitar pro 6 in does not print

Tags: 12.04

I can not make guitar pro 6 print, it can print to PDF (with errors in the margin) But the program can not print. I dont have that problem with other Ubuntu 12.04 programmes.

http://getsatisfaction.guitar-pro.com/arobas_music/topics/cannot_print_in_ubuntu_12_04

Answer (score 2):

I found a PDF programme i Ubuntu where i can downscale the file a bit so the margin problem is solved if I use a 95% scaled version and print that it looks very nice. The guitarpro people are ignoring this problem, the "support" is not supportive.

http://getsatisfaction.guitar-pro.com/arobas_music/topics/cannot_print_in_ubuntu_12_04

View print in guitar pro 6 does not look good in 100% using 200 % is very OK, se graphics below: 
http://gratisupload.dk/vis_billede/680146/

I just realized GP6 is not worth buying, tabledit under wine works much better its low priced and intuitive. The GP6 does not do 64 bits.

Comment: Your tagging policy is very difficult to understand its not very "ubuntu" or user freindly imho, also I can not use pictures to illustrate what Im trying to say. Control freak is the word that comes to mind, however I can not use that word since its not very "Ubuntu" This site is too technical to use.